# Java equivalent to Javascript location object

Tags: java, javascript

The `Location` object in javascript contains information about the url - like host, hostname, href, pathname, hash etc.

Is there an equivalent object in Java that lets me get the same information out from a html document ?

I searched google for an answer but I could not find an answer.

Comment: Do you mean like [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)? Or are you talking about getting the current page URL within a specific Java technology like Servlets or JSP or JSF, etc?

Comment: No I am talking in java SE.

Comment: Then `java.net.URL` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You will be looking for [InetAddress](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html?is-external=true)

Comment: But `IneyAdrress` does not contain URI information like the protocol, the path, etc.

Comment: That is true. In which case your option of     java.net.URL would be more suitable

Answer (score 0):

Java

import java.net.InetAddress;

`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`

Equals

TypeScript or JavaScript

`location.hostname`